# Change anaconda package location

Tags: python, anaconda

Heyo,

I have been working on a git repository (created via cookie cutter for DS) where I have several functions/scripts in a folder called `src`. Previously, I made this folder importable but unfortunately, I forgot how I did it.

I recently cloned this repo to another path but when I try to import modules from this repo (`from src.functions import foo`), my computer is pointing to the previous location of the repository. If I open an anaconda prompt and type `pip list`, it lists my `src` as an available package but the directory is the old location of the repository.

How do I update the directory that python looks for `src` in?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Add new path to `PYTHONPATH` on your machine.

Comment: @Hook Can you elaborate? When I call `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` it returns an empty string

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages. If you add to it your new repo path, it will import from there.